# How to add two matrices and get rid of Nans

Tags: matlab, nan

How can I add two matrices and keep only the numbers ignoring the NaN values?

for example:

```
A=[NaN 2 NaN];
B=[1 NaN 3];
```

I want some form of plus `C=A+B` such that:

```
C=[1 2 3]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this without using any specific function call just by setting the `NaNs` to `0s` and then performing the sum:

```
A(A~=A)=0
B(B~=B)=0
C=A+B
```

*Edit*: Another way of achieving this as @rayryeng suggested in the first comment is to use `isnan`:

```
A(isnan(A))=0
B(isnan(B))=0
C=A+B
```

Comment: I would recommend using `isnan` instead of `A ~= A` or `B ~= B`.  Not only is the intent more clear, but certain CPUs may not produce the expected answer.  Doing `isnan` does this without ambiguity.

Comment: Given both `A~=A` and `A(isnan(A))=0` work the same, I thought the first one is more nifty because it doesn't use any specific function call. Anyhow, I didn't know about the CPU dependency issue and added your suggestion as an _Edit_ to the answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @havakok, keep in mind that the caveat of this approach is that you need to modify the original variables, or else to create another copy of them. If they are large, or if you have many of them it could be either a limit or just a burden.

Comment: @EBH, I see your point, but at least we're not losing vital information doing this! Even though I couldn't find the `sum` implementation of Matlab, but I think they are using `isnan` in their implementation for handling the `omitnan` or `includenan` switches and I think this may pose the same overhead as what we have in the answer.

Comment: @hmofrad yes you are correct. Inside the function, they simply set all NaN values to 0 and they do use `isnan`. Also, `sum` is an internal function which calls a wrapper to the LAPACK FORTRAN library which is why you can't see the actual source. Nice sleuthing by the way

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`nansum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nansum.html) (you need Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox):

```
C = nansum([A;B])
```

and get:

```
C =

     1     2     3
```

Alternatively, you can use [`sum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html#input_argument_nanflag) with an excluding NaN flag:

```
C = sum([A;B],'omitnan')
```

And you will get the same result.